# Google Document AI C# Integration Sample Code

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I am new to Google Document AI, Need Integration code in Dot Net(C#) .
Need Sample code of document ai in dot net(c#)

Comment: I am also looking for the same. will share I find something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information about Client Libraries for Document AI (Including C#)

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries

And the C# Client Library Reference https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1/latest